# How to create dynamic table based on start and end time values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion

I have a question about creating dynamic table based on passed values from one page to another. On the first page I define start time, end time and increment interval. So after I pick start time let say 8:00am and pick meeting length 15min and end time will be create in intervals of 15 min based on the start time. Example end time: 8:15am,8:30am,8:45am,... and so on until my last value that can not be greater than 9:00pm. I can pick any of these values for my end time. After I pick these three values start, end and meeting length I hit submit that takes me to second page. On this page I want to create my table based on passed values. Here is my code that I have so far:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="post" action="SeconfPage.cfm">
        <fieldset>
            <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Date</th>
                <td><input type="date" id="datepicker" name="datepicker"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Start Time</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="stime" name="stime"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Length of meeting</th>
                <td>
                <select name="meeting" id="meeting">
                    <option value="">--Select length--</option>
                </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>End Time</th>
                <td><input type="text" id="etime" name="etime"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" value="Create" onClick="getTable()"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
</form>

$(function() {
        for (var i = 5; i <= 60; i += 5) {
            $('#meeting').append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '   min' + '</option>');
        }

        function setEndTime() {
            var meetingLength = parseInt($('#meeting').find('option:selected').val() || 0);
            var selectedTime = $('#stime').timepicker('getTime');
            if(selectedTime == null || selectedTime == ""){
                alert("Please select the start time");
            }else{
                selectedTime.setMinutes(selectedTime.getMinutes() + parseInt(meetingLength, 10), 0);
                $('#etime').timepicker('option', 'minTime', selectedTime);
                $('#etime').timepicker('setTime', selectedTime);
            }
        }

        $('#stime').timepicker({
            'timeFormat':'h:i a',
            'minTime': '8:00 AM',
            'maxTime': '9:00 PM',
            'step': 30
          }).on('changeTime', function () {
            setEndTime();
        });

        var count = 0;
        $('#etime').timepicker({
            'timeFormat':'h:i a' + ' (Slot '+count+')',
            'minTime': '8:00 AM',
            'maxTime': '9:00 PM',
            'step': function () {
                var val = parseInt($('#meeting').find('option:selected').val());
                count++
                return val;
            },

        });


        $('#meeting').bind('change', function () {
            setEndTime();
        });
    });

    function getTable(){
            document.myForm.submit();
    }
```

I'm trying to figure it out how and what is the best way to create table on the second page. All values are passed from my form. An for example on the second page I have:

```
start time: 8:00am
end time: 5:00pm
meeting length: 20min
```

My idea was to create a for loop something like this:

```
for(var i=stime; i<=etime; i+=meeting){
   var tbl = "<tr><td>"+stime+"-"+i+"</td></tr>"
}
```

Something like this will give me start time and next value based on the increment. Also what is the best way to store this table in the MySQL databse once table is created? I still did not figure it out how to get this to work. If anyone can give me a hint what is the best way and if I'm on the right path.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: (Edit) *what is the best way to store this table in the MySQL databse once table is created* Just my ¢, but that is something you should figure out before designing the UI. Otherwise, the front end could end up dictating a very poor database structure ... I would suggest taking a step back. Break it into steps. Decide on the optimal database design for your application first. Then work on the interface, and finally queries.

Comment: I'm still deciding which way I should go and what is the most efficient in this case. Thanks for advise.

Comment: If you're considering using integers to determine your meeting time and the duration, one way to do it is to use unix time. Unix time is pretty standard across java (the underlying engine of ColdFusion) as well as being in UTC. However, this will introduce further complexity that may be unnecessary if your application is not ever going to include more than one location. That being said, the advantage of using unix time to store your times/dates is that it will be standardized/centralized and you can use UI libraries like Moment.js to localize the time to the end user's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following (for creating table on 2nd page):

```
<cfscript>
  //existence and type checking
  param name="FORM.datepicker" type="date";
  param name="FORM.sTime" type="time";
  param name="FORM.eTime" type="time";
  param name="FORM.meeting" type="range" min=5 max=60;//minutes
  //create currentTimeSlotBegin and lastTimeSlotBegin for cfloop
  currentTimeSlotBegin = createDateTime(year(FORM.datepicker), month(FORM.datepicker), day(FORM.datepicker), hour(FORM.sTime), minute(FORM.sTime), 0);//this will be incremented, within cfloop, for each time slot
  lastTimeSlotEnd = createDateTime(year(FORM.datepicker), month(FORM.datepicker), day(FORM.datepicker), hour(FORM.eTime), minute(FORM.eTime), 0);//used only for creating lastTimeSlotBegin below
  lastTimeSlotBegin = dateAdd("n", FORM.meeting*-1, lastTimeSlotEnd);//subtract meeting length to get beginning of last time slot
</cfscript>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Time Slots for <cfoutput>#dateFormat(FORM.datepicker, "ddd, mmm dd, yyyy")#</cfoutput></th>
  </tr>
  <cfloop condition="currentTimeSlotBegin lte lastTimeSlotBegin">
    <cfset currentTimeSlotEnd = dateAdd("n", FORM.meeting, currentTimeSlotBegin)>
    <tr>
      <td><cfoutput>#timeFormat(currentTimeSlotBegin, "hh:nn tt")#-#timeFormat(currentTimeSlotEnd, "hh:nn tt")#</cfoutput></td>
    </tr>
    <cfset currentTimeSlotBegin = dateAdd("n", FORM.meeting, currentTimeSlotBegin)>
  </cfloop>
</table>
```

Thanks!,

-Aaron

Comment: @AronNeff  I have a question about this cfloop condition. So I tried to put this <cfloop condition="currentTimeSlotBegin lte lastTimeSlotBegin"> inside of another <cfloop query="qryId">. After I run that code I get output for first ID from the first loop and after that nothing. For some reason after my loop try to go second time, does not pass the condition. Do you know how that can be solved? I tried to reset values from cfloop condition in between two loops but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

Is this kinda what your looking for, its a table that is created and is populated using another table data

https://github.com/TheOriginalDeveloper/Dynamic-and-responsive-table

Comment: I was looking at this link that you sent to me but that is kind a different that I need. In my case first what I have to do is to figure it out how to convert time values, then I can use time values in for loop to create values (time range) and then build the table based on those values.

Comment: try and keep it simple, try to use it as just numbers but use a if statement to detect weather seconds/minutes/hours reach a value of 60 as per say then to increment the char before do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes, do you know what is the best way to convert time values to numbers? meeting Length value is already an integer. Just start and end time I should convert to numbers. After I submit my form and output Form.value(s) on the screen they look like this ex: 8:30am.

Comment: try and limit the user input to using data time type of input field but tbh I've not doing nothing like this before i can try and mess around and see if i can work something out but the most similar thing to this ive done is a js alarm clock

Comment: If you have anything that can help give me an update. Thank you.

Comment: @TheOriginal - Welcome to S.O. You might want to take a minute to review the [Quick Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  Answers that consist only of links are discouraged (and often deleted), as they are no longer useful when the link breaks or changes.  Consider expanding on your answer with more details, code examples, etcetera.

Answer (score 1):

I'll make some assumptions...that something is going to happen in these meeting slots, and that a meetings normally are at time *and* on a date (which is therefore just a single datetime in a database table).

Agree with Leigh, what you want to do dictates the data structure, then use a query of that to build your display of the data (table in this case). So if the data you need to store in the end was

```
dateTimeStamp                 ¦ meetingID     ¦  meetingSlotData
{ts '2015-07-04 20:00:00'}    ¦ 1             ¦  Peter Pan
{ts '2015-07-04 20:15:00'}    ¦ 1             ¦  Wendy
```

First use your datetime picker to populate the data table (just doing it manually for now)

```
 <cfset newQuery = queryNew("dateTimeStamp, meetingID, meetingSlotData","Timestamp, Integer, VarChar")>
 <cfset queryAddRow(newQuery, 2)>
 <cfset querySetCell(newQuery, "dateTimeStamp", {ts '2015-07-04 20:00:00'}, 1)>
 <cfset querySetCell(newQuery, "meetingID", 1, 1)>
 <cfset querySetCell(newQuery, "dateTimeStamp", {ts '2015-07-04 20:10:00'}, 2)>
 <cfset querySetCell(newQuery, "meetingID", 1, 2)>

 <cfdump var="#newQuery#">
```

Then query the data to build your table

```
<cfquery name="getMeeting">
    SELECT *
    FROM meetings
    WHERE id = 1
</cfquery>

<table>
<cfoutput query = "getMeeting">
    <tr><td>#dateTimeStamp#</td><td>#meetingID#</td></tr>
</cfoutput> 
</table>
```

Comment: My question is if I use this dateTimeStamp with just one time variable, how I will make time slots that I need? I did not understand fully what you tried to do in the code above. If you can explain one more time please.